# Sort lines in text file with specific separator in Linux

Tags: text, sort

I need to sort the lines of a text file (without any extension) where the lines are separated by `%`. When using `sort` command, those `%`s are also getting sorted out which I do not want.

How to sort the text file from command line or by any other method and save with same name?

For example:

filename: myfile

Before sorting>>

```
A line one
%
C line two
%
B line three
%
```

After sorting>>

```
%
%
%
A line one
B line three
C line two
```

Desired>>

```
A line one
%
B line three
%
C line two
%
```

Comment: Is the separator static (is it literally always `%`)?

Comment: yes, for this particular case, it is always `%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strip out the separator (`awk` is looking for odd lines), sort it into a temporary file (see comments) and then sed that file to add the separator back.

```
awk 'NR%2==1' myfile | sort -o tmpfile; sed -r 's/$/\n\%/g' tmpfile
```

That just outputs to `stdout` so stick a `> myfile` on the end of it if you want it to pipe that back into your file. I've left it bare so you can test it.

Sidebar: There are about a hundred different ways of handling the reinsertion of the separators. These would all work:

```
awk '{print $0"\n%"}'
while read line; do echo -e "$line\n%"; done
xargs -i^ echo -e "^\n%"  # won't work with a redirection >
```

Comment: Thanks. Its perfect. Only thing is `> myfile` is not working. It is just creating a blank `myfile`. adding `| tee log` is working. I would love to save it with name `myfile`. How to achieve that ?

Comment: @cosmicraga I forgot that `xargs` would mash up the output. It's probably easiest to swap `sed`  but the others should also work. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: If you want the output to be the same file, use `sed -i`. If you do `awk ... file ... | sort | sed > file` it will get truncated.

Comment: @fedorqui I think I disagree. It's not an in-place edit by that point, it's in-memory stream manipulation. All the data has been read out of the file (sort sees to that) so this should be safe. Just tested it on a file with 1.2million lines (inc separators) and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: It must depend on the `sed` version then. In my case it truncates the file. I checked basic examples like `sed 's/hello/you/g' a > a` or `awk '1' a | sed 's/hello/bye/g' > a`.

Comment: @oli, I am sorry to say that `awk 'NR%2==1' myfile | sort | sed -r 's/$/\n\%/g' > myfile` is still deleting the content of the file. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @cosmicraga, give a try to the same command with `sed -ir 's/$/\n\%/g'` instead of `sed -r 's/$/\n\%/g' > myfile`.

Comment: @fedorqui, it deletes the content and says 'sed: no input files'

Comment: Oh, I see. Then it may be better to just save the output to a temp file and then move to the original one.

Comment: Yeah -i won't work without an actual file and if you do `-ir` it'll treat `r` as the argument for `-i`... Anyway - I've edited the answer to use a temporary file so sorting can go into that and the be sedded back into the original file.

Comment: Expanding from the edit, the full command would be: `awk 'NR%2==1' myfile | sort -o tmpfile; sed -r 's/$/\n\%/g' tmpfile > myfile; rm tmpfile`

Comment: @oli, it works. Thank you.
@ fedorqui, thank u also.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is not the best performance solution, but this double `awk` calling can make it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n%\n"}1' file | sort | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n%\n"}1'
A line one
%
B line three
%
C line two
%
```

`RS` is "input record separator" and `ORS` "output record separator".

The output after `sort` is this, so then it is clear that we are just working with the no-% lines :

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n%\n"}1' file | sort 
A line one
B line three
C line two
```

Comment: This one also works. :) but I could not save it into the same file using `> myfile` :(. Thanks.